# Three.js website throws 403 error when uploaded to the server

Tags: html, css, json, three.js

I created a pretty simple three.js website and uploaded it to my hosting server via FileZilla, but as soon as I try to access the site I get a 403 error.

I have already spoken to the customer service of my hosting provider and they said it is due to my package.json file, I should somehow note the index.html there. Unfortunately I just have no idea how to do it, I hope someone knows the problem and can help me?
Attached is a screenshot of the structure of my website.

Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQtK1.png)

Comment: You're getting a 403 error because there is no file to serve in your website's root and you're currently trying to browse files in the root directory if you type in the domain. Move the index.html file to the root of your project folder.

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your quick response. I am very new to this topic... What is the root of my project folder?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.